# Add post_type to index.php

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I search for an hour now without result. Does anyone can explain me how to show my custom post_type (dictionnaire) in the homepage (index.php). I use 'Easy post type' to add custom post types and I checked the "Query Var" checkbox. Please help...

The only posts that appears in my homepage are the regular one.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What are you using them for? You know it requires coding, right? It is "custom" for a reason :P

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this (goes in `functions.php` or elsewhere, but not template):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_dictionnaire_in_home' );

function include_dictionnaire_in_home( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'dictionnaire' ) );
    }
}
```

Note that `index.php` template is not strictly home template. It is catch-all template that is used if no better hierarchy match is available. It's just common for home because more specific template is rarely provided for it.